# Showing error message if phone number is already registered

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, rest

I an newbie to Angular.js, i am developing a Registration page for an application. Here i am taking user phone number as primary key. In the registration form after user enter his phone number i am doing a AJAX call to data base to check the number is already exist or not. I am successfully done that part. but i i am not getting how to show error message to the user if the user already registered.

my code for index.html

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.contactno.$invalid  && (userForm.contactno.$dirty || submitted) }">
     <label>ContactNo</label>
     <input phone type="text" name="contactno" class="form-control" ng-model="user.phone" placeholder="Your Contact No" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" maxlength="10">
     <p ng-show="userForm.contactno.$error.pattern  && (userForm.contactno.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Enter a valid contactno.</p>
</div>
```

Here is my AJAX call:

```
  myAppDirectives.
    directive('phone', function() {
  return {
      restrice: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          angular.element(element).bind('blur', function() {
          var phnNum = this.value;
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:8087/users/'+phnNum,
          dataType: 'application/json',
          type: 'GET',

success: function( data, status, headers, cfg ){

        console.log("data" +data);

       },
error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        if(result.responseText.length===0){
        console.log("you can register now");    
       }
     else{
        console.log("User with this number is already registered");

      }
   }            
  });           
 });              
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can show the user friendly message in the form of alert window. Please clarify your qstn. http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js//common-user-interface-patterns/displaying-a-flash-notice-failure-message.html

Comment: @kiran Thanks for replay , Do i need to write the alert message in AJAX call itself?

Comment: You can write the logic in the callback functions i.e. "success" & "error".

Comment: You can also use ngMessages module from Angular JS to design the custom error messages. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages

Comment: Please give a try and share your views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to display error message in your page. Just pass the error message to scope and display it in your relative page. Like this. Insted of Ajax make practice to use $http.post or $http.get in your angular request.

```
$scope.checkNumber=function(phnNum){
         $http.post('http://localhost:8087/users', phnNum).success(function(data){
             if(data == "false"){
                 $scope.error = 'User with this number is already registere.';

             } else {
                 $scope.submitTrueMessage = 'you can register now';
                 $scope.error = null;
             }
         });
    };
```

And this is how you can show error message in your view.

```
<span style="color:red"> {{error}} </span>
```

Hope this information is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an alert when the phone number is exist in the database you should try to code in your api.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logic in the callback functions i.e. "success" & "error".

OR You can also use ngMessages module from Angular JS to design the custom error messages.

docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages

Answer (score 0):

check the phone number if its already exits through a loop in your database then use

{{ error }}

and define the error in your code part in if part and in else part store the phone number.